# How to dynamically positioning html table by using css properties?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem to positioning my table under the html grid. Please find my clear explanation below:

I have a html grid as below, and Its css properties:

```
<div class="teststatus">
<span class="description"> com.online.Regression</span>
<span class="startTimer"> Test Started at:11:55:45</span>
<span class="endTimer"> Test Ended at:11:55:58 </span
<span class="status"><b> Status:</b> FAILED</span>
</div>
```

Css Properties:

```
#main{               //It's id which is common for all the html grid tag
width:1500px;
position:relative;
background-color:#eeeff4;
left:40px;
}

.teststatus
{
position:absolute;
top:500px;
width:1500px;
background-color:#eeeff4;
}
```

I have n number of html grid as above. When I'm clicking the grid, and It has to show the table which belongs to it. as below:

```
<div class="assertiondatTable">
<table class="assertionTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>TC_ID</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Expected Result</th>
<th>Actual Result</th>
<th> Status </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> TC_DirectDebit_001</td>
<td> Check the direct debit functionality </td>
<td> The record should be inserted successfully</td>
<td> The record is inserted successfully</td>
<td> PASSED</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

css properties for the table:

```
.assertionTable
{
outline:1px solid green;
left: 300px;
position:absolute;
width:900px;

}
```

Each html grid have one #id attribute which is main for the grid, and table. The table always belongs to grid. You can assume an # is ancestor, grid is child,and table is grand child for this design.

So, far I didn't face any issue with this design(Single record), and It works perfect. but the problem when I add another grid (same as above code, and the second grid have #TC2 and same content) the first grid "**table**" is overwriting into second html grid.

Can somebody help me to solve this issue? I wanna dynamically place the table which is under grid. The table maximum have 20 records If some one click the grid then It has to display and hide the table(Already done). My problem here to positioning on the page.If the table is hidden I just wanna maintain 10 px distance from each grid. If its opened, then I need to get space dynamically to view the whole table without overwrite other grid/ table.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Please please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

-Sasi

Comment: can you create a fiddle demo

Comment: Are you using and trying this fr Extent reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround everything in a content div with `clear: both` CSS property, and this *should* make everything stack correctly, or rather prevent things floating over it (see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)).

It's difficult to solve without a fiddle - I tried to put one together for this but wasn't successful as I'm not 100% understanding your page layout and don't have any of the JavaScript that I think you're using (or all of the CSS for all the `<span>` classes).

Also be sure to correct your syntax error - missing closing bracket here: `<span class="endTimer"> Test Ended at:11:55:58 </span` I don't know if that would affect it.

Hope this helps - please provide a fiddle demo if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. It works perfect. It's better to close this case. Once again thank you so much - Lyall.